# SQL Server Query Hint for Fast Rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a MSSQL 2008 db with a stored procedure that returns a result set with 1-10 rows and 5 columns. I have made all of the optimizations I can think of and my query plans show good index seeks everywhere. The .net 4.0 code that obtains the result set uses an old school ado.net SqlDataReader in an effort to get every millisecond of speed from the data read (no indirection from EF or LINQtoSQL etc). I am trying to understand if the "fast row" query hint will actually get me any more speed. I don't have enough of the system built out to test things through, and key Bing/Google searches came up relatively dry, so I am looking for any insight on this.

Thanks.

Comment: "returns a result set with 1-10 rows and 5 columns" - and what's slow about it? Query Hints are rarely a good idea....

Comment: Why not try it and see once it's built? Stick `OPTION (FAST 10);` onto your query and see what happens? As Mitch points out, I can't see that 10 rows would be that slow anyway...